# Pass environment variable through to another user when being run as sudo

Tags: tomcat, rhel5, sudo

I am installing Tomcat on a RHEL5 machine, and am having some trouble starting it, because JAVA_HOME isn't set. Tomcat is being started using

```
sudo /sbin/service tomcat start
```

and runs under the user `tomcat`. When I am logged in as myself or as the root user, `JAVA_HOME` is properly set (using `/etc/profile.d/java.sh`). I am guessing that this isn't being properly passed through by sudo.

Can someone point me in the direction of the change I need to make to get this variable either passed through by sudo or picked up by the `tomcat` user? I believe there are a number of ways.

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to add JAVA_HOME to the tomcat start up script, which should be in /etc/init.d

Answer (score 1):

mazianni's answer is correct.

More info:

For a non-interactive shell `/etc/profile` is not read and therefore `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` aren't read either.

`JAVA_HOME` is set in your interactive shell. `sudo` strips out most environment variables. You could configure the `env_keep` in `/etc/sudoers` to allow `JAVA_HOME` through but if you ever set tomcat to automatically start this method will no longer work. (Hence mazianni's solution is the best.)

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo -E <your command>`. This preserves (most of) the environment. See `man sudo` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily set a variable before execution in BASH.  This will be available to the command immediately following.

`JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java sudo /sbin/service tomcat start`

Answer (score 0):

Read [`man sudoers`](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudoers.man.html).

Using [`visudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/visudo.man.html) (never edit `/etc/sudoers` directly!), you can choose to set `!env_reset` to globally allow (most) environment variables to pass through `sudo`, or add to `env_keep` which specific variables should be kept.